# jquery mobile - how detect page top

Tags: jquery-mobile, offset

I want to know how much of page is scrolled.

I tried this code not helped me:

```
$('html').offset().top
```

also:

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

Comment: How has `$(window).scrollTop()` failed? can you post your code?

Comment: you can try with body ($('body').scrollTop())